# How to get input text value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to output a manipulated input value of a text type input tag, but it seems to be harder than I thought it will be. I don't want to use alert or console.log kind of outputting, but appending to the page as new content. Here I didn't manipulate the input, since I'm not even able to output it, which is my first goal then.

my html code for the corresponding part is:

```
<div class="middle topic"> 

            <div id="inputnav">
                <button id="sendd">SEND</button>
            </div>

            <input type="text" value="" id="iPf">

            <div id="oPf">
            output
            </div>

 </div>
```

and here is the full javascript. I linked it at the end of the html before the closing body tag, after a jquery-1.12.2.min.js linking.

```
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/

$(document).ready(function () {
"use strict";

var inPuttext = document.getElementById("iPf").innerHTML;
var outPutfield = document.getElementById("oPf");

function appendOutput(where, what) {
    where.innerHTML = what;
};

$('#sendd').click(function () {
    appendOutput(outPutfield, inPuttext);
});
```

});

I can't figure out why it doesn't work. When I click the send button the only thing happens is that the "output" disappears from the #oPf div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `value` property not `innerHTML` to get value from input element.
- Get the value in `click` handler to get updated value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";
  var outPutfield = document.getElementById("oPf");

  function appendOutput(where, what) {
    where.innerHTML = what;
  };
  $('#sendd').click(function() {
    var inPuttext = document.getElementById("iPf").value;
    appendOutput(outPutfield, inPuttext);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="middle topic">
  <div id="inputnav">
    <button id="sendd">SEND</button>
  </div>
  <input type="text" value="" id="iPf">
  <div id="oPf">
    output
  </div>
</div>
```

**But,** If you are using `jQuery`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";
  $('#sendd').click(function() {
    $('#oPf').html($("#iPf").val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="middle topic">
  <div id="inputnav">
    <button id="sendd">SEND</button>
  </div>
  <input type="text" value="" id="iPf">
  <div id="oPf">
    output
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this, you will get output in output div.

HTML UPDATE

```
<div id="inputnav">
            <button id="sendd" onClick="fn()">SEND</button>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT UPDATE

```
function fn(){
var inPuttext = document.getElementById("iPf").value;
document.getElementById("oPf").innerHTML = inPuttext;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

use `.value` to get entered value of input box.

get value inside calling function so that you can get entered value in inputbox

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
"use strict";
  function appendOutput(where, what) {
      where.innerHTML = what;
  };

  $('#sendd').click(function () {
      var inPuttext = document.getElementById("iPf").value; // use .value to get entered value of input box , get value inside calling function so that you can get entered value in inputbox
      var outPutfield = document.getElementById("oPf");
      appendOutput(outPutfield, inPuttext);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="middle topic"> 
      <div id="inputnav">
           <button id="sendd">SEND</button>
       </div>
       <input type="text" value="" id="iPf">
       <div id="oPf">
           output
        </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$("#oPf").html($("#iPf").val());`

```
$('#sendd').click(function() {
   $("#oPf").html($("#iPf").val());
 });
```

> Refer : [Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74gzcpfa/)

```js
$('#sendd').click(function() {
  $("#oPf").html($("#iPf").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="middle topic">

  <div id="inputnav">
    <button id="sendd">SEND</button>
  </div>

  <input type="text" value="" id="iPf">

  <div id="oPf">
    output
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

inPuttext should be

```
var inPuttext =document.getElementById("iPf").value
```

above code should come inside the click event.because we need to get the  input value after it entered.My answer as follows

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            "use strict";


            var outPutfield = document.getElementById("oPf");

            function appendOutput(where, what) {
                console.log(what);
                where.innerHTML = what;
            }
            ;

            $('#sendd').click(function () {
                var inPuttext = document.getElementById("iPf").value;
                appendOutput(outPutfield, inPuttext);
                console.log('asd');
            });
        });
```